# how to change referrer-policy in react js

Tags: reactjs, reactjs.net, referrer-policy

I want to change referral policy in chrome the default policy for new update in chrome is strict-origin-when-cross-origin I need to change it to no-referrer-when-downgrade

I am using reactjs how can I change the policy

THank you

Comment: Would be great if you could eloberate the question

Comment: In google chrome latest update they have changed referral policy to "strict-origin-when-cross-origin"  https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2020/07/referrer-policy-new-chrome-default                                      I need to get back old referral policy "no-referrer-when-downgrade" with the help of code, i am using react js for client side

Answer (score 4):

Add this line in index.html head to go back to old referral policy

```
<meta name="referrer" content="no-referrer-when-downgrade" />
```

Comment: Worked fine. one point to add here is :- 
If no referrer policy is set, the browser's default policy will be used.